# Customizing Flex (4) Tabbar

Tags: apache-flex, skinning

I 'm new to Flex (4) and just learning by doing! Recently i got the requirement to make a tabbar look like the following (got from a known site)

[image]

I think i have to use a skin!? If yes how to achieve this? Asking because this component has buttons in it!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a spark TabBar component in Flex 4.

Create a new Skin for the TabBar this is based on the default spark.skins.spark.TabBarSkin

In this skin, you will see there is a DataGroup component that displays buttons. These buttons are the TabBar buttons.
So you need to change the Skin of these buttons :

```
<s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="YourOwnBlackTabBarButtonSkin" />
```

Comment: thanks florian!will give it a try and come up with the results!